# PeriodicWorkRequest in android

Tags: android, android-workmanager

I want my task to be executed periodically, so I am using PeriodicWorkRequest of WorkManger and i set up 20 minutes as a period(time interval).but it is executing several times in that time period.can someone help me out?

```
public void startButtonClicked(View view) {

        PeriodicWorkRequest periodicWorkRequest = new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(

                PeriodicRequest.class, 15, TimeUnit.MINUTES
        ).build();

        WorkManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).enqueue(periodicWorkRequest);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a flex interval. PeriodicWorkRequest will fire when it schedules without adding a flex interval.

```
           14min              1min              14min               1min
 [     before flex     |     flex     ][     before flex     |     flex     ]...
 [   cannot run work   | can run work ][   cannot run work   | can run work ]...
 \____________________________________/\____________________________________/...
                interval 1                            interval 2             ...(repeat)
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder

Answer (score 0):

If you need to have a single `PeriodicWorkReques` that executes your Worker with a period of 20 minutes, enqueue it as unique work.

You can find more information on WorkManager documentation. The basic is to use [`WorkManager.enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(String, ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy, PeriodicWorkRequest)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkManager.html?authuser=1#enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(java.lang.String,%20androidx.work.ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy,%20androidx.work.PeriodicWorkRequest)) instead of the `WorkManager.enqueue(PeriodicWorkRequest)` you're currently using.

If you just need to be sure to have your worker executed you should use `KEEP` as [`ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy). It's the cheapest for WorkManager and doesn't require to stop your Worker if it's already executing.

For more information on WorkManager and periodic work, you can take a look at my blog: [WorkManager Periodicity](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/workmanager-periodicity-ff35185ff006).